# index_template is not applicable for next day

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I set on custom template mapping for my index. Manually execute the command in kibana devtools and it's worked.
How i am verify this work like again i push the index from logstash and i can see index was created and it used my custom template_mapping.
 My question is, what is happening for next day another new index created but it doesn't use my custom template that i had created yesterday, is there any idea that could help me to fix this ?
Below is example of mapping use

```
PUT _template/myindex
{
  "index_patterns": ["myindex-*"],

  "settings": {

    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "abct": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry please ignore this as the issue is with the index_pattern created is different with what i defined in the template pattern